# good software to practice communication skills

Tags: windows, educational, communication

I stammer at times and this is becoming a big obstacle for me in any interviews and in daily life.I am trying to overcome this by practicing

1. Read out the article by seeing and record it
2. Say some thing about a random article and record it

Finally analyze how it went.

But my problem is I am stumbling when speaking with someone.

So my question: Is there any good software that I can converse daily to improve my communication skills?

Comment: What features are you looking for beyond those of a standard sound-recording program?

Comment: @Kodiologist:some thing which can ask some random questions to converse on a topic

Comment: I recommend you practice with a live human being.  The key will be to find someone you can relax with.  Two ideas: (1) your local literacy volunteers group -- you could either be honest or you could downplay your literacy skills in the intake. (2) sign up to be a conversational partner with someone who is learning English as a second language. // At the same time, it can be helpful to work with a therapist. // For practicing, I recommend reading **poems** out loud. // You might also find it helpful to take some fun theater classes that do not involve performing if you do not wish to perform.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but for future searchers, oh man, I've been in the same boat with the stammering thing, it can really throw you off, especially during interviews. I stumbled upon this site, https://PracticeInterview.ai, and it's been a game-changer for me. You can paste in a job description or use one of theirs to get mock interview questions. Then, you answer them, and the AI gives you feedback and a grade. It's like having a personal coach that helps you get better at speaking smoothly. Definitely worth a shot for practicing in a low-pressure environment!